# Does $A\in B$ imply $A\subset B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Question: Does $A\in B$ imply $A\subset B$ and does $A\in B$ and $B\in C$ imply $A\in C$?

I've been trying to find examples to get some intuition for this and I've come up with the following:

**Example 1:** Suppose that $A = \{1\}$, $B = \{\{1\},2\}$. I'd say that $A$ is an element of $B$ and $A$ is a subset of $B$.

**Example 2:** Suppose that $A = \{1\}$, $B = \{\{1\},2\}$ and $C = \{\{\{1\},2\},3\}$. Now $A\in B$, $B\in C$ but $A\not\in C$, right?

I think my confusion stems from the fact that I'm not sure how $B = \{\{1\},2\}$ vs $B = \{1,2\}$ determines whether $A$ is an element and/or a subset of $B$.

Comment: $1 \in A$ but $1 \notin B$ (we have $\{1\} \in B$ instead), so I don't think that $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: In your first example, $\{A\}$ is a subset of $B$; $A$ is not.

Comment: The key difference between element and subset is identified by braces. $1 \in \{ 1,2,3 \}$ and $\{ 1 \} \in \{ \{ 1 \}, 2,3 \}$. In words, $a$ is an element of $B$ if it is in the "list enclosed by braces". Thus $1$ is an element of the first set above, and $\{ 1 \}$ is an element of the second one. But $\{ 1 \} \notin \{ 1,2,3 \}$.

Comment: In order to identify a subset of a set $B$, you must pick up zero or more elements of $B$ and enclose them between braces. Thus, $\{ 1,3 \} \subseteq \{ 1,2,3 \}$ as well as $\emptyset = \{ \quad \} \subseteq \{ 1,2,3 \}$ as well as $\{ \{ 1 \},2 \} \subseteq \{ \{ 1 \} ,2,3 \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Taking $A=\{\emptyset\}$ and $B=\{A\} = \{\{\emptyset\}\}$, you have $A\in B$, but not $A\subseteq B$.

---

Furthermore, in Example $1$, $A=\{1\}$ is **not** a subset of the set $B=\{\{1\},2\}$, because it is **not** true that every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$. Specifically, $1$ is an element of $A$, but $1$ is **not** an element of $B$.

$B$ is a set with two elements, one of them is equal to $2$, the other one is equal to $\{1\}$, and $1$ is not equal to any of these two elements.

Answer (score 2):

No : if $A = \{1\}$, $B = \{\{1\},2\}$, then $A\in B$ but $A\not\subset B \ $ ; all the subsets of $B$ are : $\emptyset,\ \{\{1\}\},\ \{\{2\}\},\ \{\{1\},2\}$ (moreover $B$ can't have more than $4$ subsets!).

For example 2 you are right.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So the difference lies in the fact that $\{1\}\neq 1$? How would you call $1$ where $1\in A$? The point in $A$?

Comment: @Mr.President Yes, exactly : $\{ 1\} \neq 1 $ (to figure out better, imagine $1$ as a bottle :  $\{ 1\}  $ would be a box containing a bottle, it is totally different). If $1\in A$, $1$ is called an element of $A$.

Comment: @Mr.President In the same spirit, $\{\emptyset\}\neq \emptyset$ (which is more confusing, I admit), but it is the same idea : if you imagine $\emptyset$ as an empty box,  $\{\emptyset\}$ would be a box containing an empty box.

Answer (score 1):

Not all sets satisfy this property; in fact, this property is the definition of a [transitive set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set).

Neither of your examples exhibit are transitive. In Example 1, notice that $1 \in A$ but $1 \not\in B$ (even though $\{1\} \in B$), so that $A \not\subseteq B$. In Example 2, you run into more or less the same problem.

Examples of transitive sets include the [von Neumann ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals) and the sets in the [cumulative hierarchy $V_{\alpha}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe).

Answer (score 0):

Your question gives an occasion to emphasize the distinction between :

(1) not implying that proposition P is true

and

(2) implying that proposition P is false ( not-true).

The fact that A is a member of B certainly does not imply that A is included in B.

Thousands of examples could be found.

But, precisely, due to the fact that this non-implication is so often  confirmed, we tend to think that : "A belongs to B" implies that "A is not a subset of B".

And surprisingly, when one discovers the construction of natural numbers, one has to recognize that this induction is false.

For  example :  2 is defined as {0,1} and 3 is defined as {0,1,2}. The number 2 is a member of the number 3. But is as also a subset of 3.